# how to replace a string in a cell with multi row character in matlab

Tags: regex, string, matlab

i am using a template and regexprep to replace character. my template is huge so i can't post it here. so consider that my template name is templateGetC. I use

```
regexprep(templateGetC,'<final_bus_name>',component_name);
```

to replace the 'final_bus_name' in my template with the component_name which has the value 'machine'.
but what if i want to replace it with a multi row string. like if

```
a= ' start the experiment
    analyse the content
 end the experiment'
```

and if i  want to replace 'final_bus_name' with 'a' it throws me an error that
'The third argument (REPLACE) must be a one-dimensional array of char or cell arrays of strings.'

is there any other way to replace it. i tried num2cell but it's horrible and just messes up the data.

i also tried strrep but it throws the error 'Input strings must have one row.'

I tried cell2str but that doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try using "\n" inside the multiline replacement string? Acc. to http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html, `\n` operator is available with replacement strings.

Comment: in which line is it mentioned about the multiline replacement...its just mentioned that it will replace multiple lines with a single string but not single string with multiple lines. i am also trying cellstr now. let me update if it works